# How can i set default color on element after mouse out D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a forced directed graph and I like to highlight its parents and make them a bit bigger than others I can make them new colour and make them bigger but I cannot return them to their default size and colour.
Whenever I move my mouse on the element it changes all of them green but when I move out my mouse only centre element changes colour but it does not return to its own colour it returns to colour that I put my mouse on.

```
function highlightParents(d) {
    var colour = d3.event.type === 'mouseover' ? 'green' : color(d.group);
    d3.select('#id-' + parseInt(d.id)).style('fill', colour);
    var bid = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < link._groups[0].length; i++) {

        if (link._groups[0][i].attributes[0].value.replace("t-", "") == d.id) //target
        {

            bid += link._groups[0][i].attributes[1].value.replace("s-", ""); //source
            d.id = link._groups[0][i].attributes[1].value.replace("s-", "");  //source


            var colour = d3.event.type === 'mouseover' ? 'green' : color(d.group);
            d3.select('#id-' + parseInt(d.id)).style('fill', colour);
            var setr = d3.event.type === 'mouseover' ? '7' : 5;
            d3.select('#id-' + parseInt(d.id)).style('r', setr);                         
            i = 0;
            if (link._groups[0][i].attributes[1].value == "304410") {
                break;
                d3.selectAll('#id-' + parseInt(d.id)).style('fill', (d.group));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use 'mouseout' event?

For example:

```
function highlightParents(d) {
  var colour = color(d.group);
  if (d3.event.type === 'mouseover') colour = 'green';
  if (d3.event.type === 'mouseout') colour = 'red';
  ...
```

Comment: var colour = d3.event.type === 'mouseover' ? 'green' : color(d.group);
i think this asks already if over or out but thanks for answer